# Golang logging strategy

Tags: logging, go, glog

Standard `log` package in Go does not support levels unlike `logging` standard library in Python.

Many packages resort to third-party log packages such as `glog` or `logrus`.

What is best logging strategy for Go when importing third-party packages that may or may not use third-party logging package.

Comment: what the heck are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

So, I think you're asking, what if a package I'm using uses plain old https://golang.org/pkg/log/ and my main package uses something special, like `log.Info`, `log.Warn`, `log.Error`, and `log.Debug`?

If the package exposes the `log.Logger` object to you, you can use `SetFlags`, `SetOutput`, `SetPrefix` to alter what those log messages look like, or silence them altogether, but you can't make them play nice with your special third-party logging package.

For example if a third part package looks like this:

```
package sayhello

import (
      "log"
      "os"
)

type SayHello {
      Logger *log.Logger
}

func NewSayHello() (SayHello) {
      logger, _ := os.OpenFile("/tmp/tmp.log",  os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
      var sh SayHello
      sh.Logger = log.New(logger, "SAY HELLO LOGGER: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
      return sh
}

func (sh SayHello) Run() {
      sh.Logger.Println("Hello. I ran!")
}
```

Then I can silence it like this:

```
package main

import (
      "sayhello"
      "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
      sh := sayhello.NewSayHello()
      sh.Run()
      // output is: 2016/08/10 16:47:46 SAY HELLO LOGGER: Hello. I ran!
      sh.Logger.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
      sh.Run()
      // output is nothing
}
```

But there's really no way you can translate log statements in another package like `log.Println` in a into something like `log.Info`, or `log.Debug`, which is what you're looking for.